# Bootstrap: center navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a navbar on my testing website http://ba.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/ that is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#ark">Architektur</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="/table.html">Wohnungen</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#about">Ausstattung</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Lage</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Galerie</a>
                </li>

                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top"></a>

        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

how can i do something like this?

[Navigation Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqk07.jpg)

Basically i have to center the navigation and put the logo on right and the sentence on left and give to this section that shape. **(I mean the border-left cutted around 25deg.)**

Thanks in advice

Comment: Are you able to add a row above the navbar?

Comment: @Lxske yes, and the navbar has to be into that row?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the content you want in a seperate row above the navbar as in my following code example.
The first col-sm-1 is where you need to do some "hacking".

1. Give the first col-sm-1 the background-color;
2. For the diagonal part: add an image to this div, displaying this diagonal.
3. To put it in the right place and make it adapt to smaller screens, add the attributes I've put in the example's css.

You might need to set the margin or padding on these rows to 0.

**Example**

```
<style>
.dark-bg {
    background-color: #645246;
}
#diagonal {
    display:block; 
    float:right; 
    max-height: 100%; 
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1" id="dark-bg">
            <img class="diagonal" src="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- pay off text -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <!--logo-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row dark-bg">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <!--........-->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also use a CSS gradient instead of this. But as gradients are supposed to flow over smoothly from one color to another, the result isn't as smooth as you'd like and as you can achieve with the image hack.

Comment: Or you could just put all those elements into a an image and put that image in the row above the navbar.. (removing any excess padding/margin)